# Where can I find logs for failed sudo attempts on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, security, logs, sudo, administrator

I am aware that older versions of OS X use secure.log, but I have been unable to find any definite answers as to where the the output log goes for for attempting to run a command with sudo privileges on a non-admin account, on macOS Sierra. When we see the command feedback "this incident will be reported"; where is that reported to and how can I see it on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 11):

The sudo logs now go to the new [unified logging system](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging) in macOS 10.12, which can be searched using the `log` command.

For example, to show all sudo logs from the last 3 hours:

```
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "sudo"' --last 3h
```

To search all sudo logs for messages containing the string "user NOT in sudoers":

```
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "sudo" and eventMessage contains "user NOT in sudoers"'
```

Use `man log` or `log help show` to learn more about how to use the command.