# Any way to get the last times the screen was unlocked in macOS?

Tags: macos, lockscreen

I'd be immensely grateful if someone helped me get the last screen unlocks (such as by going to the Apple menu > lock screen).  With unlock I mean when you lock the screen then you have to unlock it by entering the password.  I guess this is registered in some log file or there's some Terminal command to get this.

I guess this must be possible because, when you use parental controls and you set up a time limit for a user, if the user locks the screen, the time on lock screen doesn't seem to count against the allowed time, which seems to imply that lock screens are registered in some log file??

The following is in a screenshot of an excerpt from the terminal output after running the High Sierra code listed in @JBis's answer:
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you go to the Console app on your Mac (it is located in Applications/ Utilities folder) and click on "Macs Analytics Data" which appears on the left side of the window. This report has a message "loginwindow" and is stamped with a time and has the word "screenlock" on the same line. I just locked and screen and then unlocked it and I got that message. You could grep out all the "loginwindow" terms and the "screenlock" terms. This should give you a list of times these events happened.

This log can be located with Finder by right-clicking it > reveal in finder (at least in macOS High Sierra)

Comment: Wow! that seems to be the one, but it seems to show only the last 3 days, is there a way to see more time back?

Comment: That I don't know.  Sorry.

Comment: Best I can tell my messages go back 5 days.  It looks like a search on "Lockscreen" is best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what should I do so you receive this bounty stuff?  ..never done it before.

Comment: At work we need to get the last usage for any of the macs we receive for repair, this may help a lot.  Being able to unlock the mac is a good piece of data that the user was actually using the machine.

Comment: Wait, I just found out if I keep trying to scroll up the viewing window, it actually works about every third time and takes me back even further in time.   I think if you accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it, I will be awarded the bounty points.

Comment: yep, I could get more time back by going out and into this log again by repeating scrollups.  I wonder were this log file is actually located in the volume..

Comment: I found this log by right-clicking it > show in finder

Comment: That may help. i'm looking for log file now.

Comment: the logs are in /var/log  i've looked there but there is a lot of info.

Comment: There should be an icon next to my answer to award me the bounty points.  Please check that too.  Thanks.

Comment: @jmh I searched `loginwindow` and nothing containing screenlock turned up.

Comment: if you lock your screen and then unlock it it will produce the message in the "Mac Analytics Data" report.  I tested it again and it works.

Comment: why the downvote?  I gave a valid answer!

Comment: @jmh that was me before the hole thing in chat. Couldn't change until edit was made. Just changed to an upvote though.

Comment: doesn't work on Sonoma 14.3.1

Answer (score 29):

It appears different versions of macOS use different logs to repersent this. None of which, I have found, **show a different log for a "login" or an "unlock"**. I have answered the next best thing: How to find all logins/unlocks. The following terminal commands will show you the date in time in which a login or unlock occurred.

---

With the help of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276780/263848) answer, and spending an hour looking through logs I figured this out:

P.S. You can additionally use the helpful `--last` tag to limit to a specific time relative to now. For example `--last 5m` would only be the last 5 minutes, `--last 5h` would be the last 5 hours, and `--last 5d` would be last 5 days.

---

### macOS Mojave

**Check for blocked unlock attempts (Invalid password or Touch ID):**

```
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info | grep "LUIAuthenticationServiceProvider activate]_block_invoke"
```

**Explanation:** The command will look through the logs and find ones that are from the process `"loginwindow"` and contain `LUIAuthenticationServiceProvider activate]_block_invoke`.

---

**Check for valid unlock attempts (Valid password or Touch ID):**

```
 log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info | grep "LUIAuthenticationServiceProvider deactivateWithContext:]_block_invoke"
```

**Explanation:** The command will look through the logs and find ones that are from the process `"loginwindow"` and contain `LUIAuthenticationServiceProvider deactivateWithContext:]_block_invoke`.

---

### macOS High Sierra

**WIP**

**Check for blocked unlock attempts (Invalid password or Touch ID):**

...

---

**Check for valid unlock attempts (Valid password or Touch ID):**

```
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info | grep "LAClient evaluatePolicy:options:uiDelegate:reply:]_block_invoke"
```

---

### macOS Sierra

**Check for blocked unlock attempts (Invalid password or Touch ID):**

```
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info | grep "Verify password called with PAM auth set to YES, but pam handle == nil"
```

---

**Check for valid unlock attempts (Valid password or Touch ID):**

```
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info | grep "SecKeychainLogin result: 0, password was supplied"
```

Comment: I tried both and they don't return anything.  You seem to be aimed in the right direction.  I'm not very literate with Terminal, what do those search, the system.log?, I couldn't find any "UIAuthenticationServiceProvider deactivateWithContext:]_block_invoke" in the system.log.
Thanks a lot for your effort, I really need this.

Comment: @Antonio23249 See update.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks again…well, this doesn’t seem to be working, I locked then unlocked the screen at 16:42:50 then restarted the machine and 16:06:10, I waited for a couple of minutes to give the logs time to catch up.
According to this the last unlock was on 2018-07-28 17:13:28.241846+0100  right?

This is a Mac Mini 2014 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Well a login maybe also trigger this log because a login is well unlocking it. Did the 16:42:50 event even show? Theoretically it should be the second one.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the result to my original post above (I couldn't add it anywhere else).  I've added it again, first screenshot I added wasn't right

Comment: Go back more. Or is that it.

Comment: also, how could I guest just the last 10 or so?  I'm trying to add --last 10 but I don't know the right syntax

Comment: I will check soon but there you go. The screenshot shows the 16:42 event. Full logins trigger this log also (which I believe it should because it is an unlock) which we cant control.

Comment: I've just teste it twice again and it's not showing screen unlocks...thanks for your help all the same, please let me know if you get anything else

Comment: That's odd I just tested it and it worked. Also from your screenshots it appears it worked. Are you sure you aren't missing an flag in the command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80818/discussion-between-antonio23249-and-jbis).

Answer (score 4):

MacOS Catalina has a log format different from Mojave.  Based on the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332226/324977) from [JBis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/263848/jbis), I wrote a script for Catalina called lockunlock.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh
PERIOD=1d
if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
    PERIOD=$1
fi
echo "Times of Mac screen lock and unlock events in the past ${PERIOD}:"
SEARCH_FOR="going inactive, create activity semaphore|releasing the activity semaphore"
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info --last ${PERIOD} | grep -E "${SEARCH_FOR}" | cut -c '1-32 141-155'
```

To arrive at the desired search term, I locked and unlocked my computer to make sure there were events, then viewed the last minute of log with

```bash
log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info --last 1m | less
```

Comment: I have developed a more sophisticated script and published it to https://github.com/lesgrieve/lockunlock. This works with Catalina and Big Sur.

Answer (score 2):

In Catalina the solution I finally arrived at is:

1. Open Terminal

   - If you are not logged in as an admin, then use `su username` to first authenticate as admin "username". I use this because I'm checking my kid's login history on his Mac without having to log him out and disrupt his stuff.
2. `log show --last 1d | grep "UserActivity Assertion"`

   - If you want to see more or less history back in time, change the "1d" to "2h" or "10m" (see documentation by running `man log`).
   - If you omit the `--last` modifier, it will take a really long time to run, maybe more than 10 minutes.

This seems to reliably show each time the machine was woken from sleep by the user unlocking the lock screen with their password.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Monterey, I updated the base snippets' syntax in this thread. You can view a timestamped log message for each occurrence of someone unlocking your Mac in the last hour with this command:

```
log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "lockUIPresentedWithoutSuccessfulUnlock = NO")' --style syslog --last 1h
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the seconds since the last unlock/lock:

```
function  getlastunlock-darwin() {
    date="$(log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info --last 1d | command rg "going inactive, create activity semaphore|releasing the activity semaphore" | tail -n1 |cut -c 1-31)" fromnow
}
function fromnow() {
    python3 -c 'import datetime ; from dateutil.parser import parse ; import os
date = parse(os.environ["date"])
print((datetime.datetime.now(date.tzinfo) - date).total_seconds())'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and type

```
last
```

this should provide log info

here's the manual page of this command :

[last manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are you sure that one shows screen unlocks?  it seems to show only actual log-ins

Comment: You are correct, @Antonio23249. A screen unlock is not a new login. `last` only shows last logins. From `man last`: _Last will list the sessions of specified users, ttys, and hosts, in reverse time order.  Each line of output contains the user name, the tty from which the session was conducted, any hostname, the start and stop times for the session, and the duration of the session.  If the session is still continuing or was cut short by a crash or shutdown, last will so indicate._

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway, I've started a bounty on it.   I guess this must be possible because, when you use parental controls and you set up a time limit for a user, if the user locks the screen, the time on lock screen doesn't seem to count against the allowed time, which seems to imply that lock screens are registered in some log file??